# How to interpret frequency decomposition of a time series?

Tags: time-series, interpretation, frequency

Consider a time-series $x_t$ at, say, quarterly frequency.

- I perform a discrete Fourier transform (DFT) $z(f)$ of $x_t$.
- Then, for each $z(f)$ I perform the inverse transform and get $x_t(f)$, that is a time series associate with a frequency $f$.
  (Namely, $x_t(f)$ is given by the sum of the inverse transform of $z(f)$ and $z(-f)$.)
- The sum of all the $x_t(f)$ over $f$ gives the original $x_t$.

Now I want to simply investigate how each $x_t(f)$ relates with other time-series.

My only problem is **how to interpret** $f$, or, put otherwise, I have $\frac{N}{2}$ time-series $x_t(f)$ (where $N$ is the number of points used in the DFT) but I don't know how to associate each $x_t(f)$ to a frequency in the correct unit of measure.

Recall that my original time series is at quarterly frequency. But I would understand the general rule, too.